# TextView Gravity.CENTER not centering Vertically

Tags: android, textview, centering, gravity

I have a TextView `tv` , on which I write some text. Then a Bitmap is extracted from the TextView and this Bitmap is then drawn on a canvas. I want the text in the TextView to be centered, both vertically and horizontally, for which I use tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER).
However the text ends up being centered only horizontally.
Here is the code creating the TextView and setting all the parameters:

```
tv.layout(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);
tv.setTextSize(60);
tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tv.setText(text);
tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
textBmp = tv.getDrawingCache().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

And here is how I draw it into my canvas

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawBitmap(textBmp, 0, 0, null);

    }
}
```

What do I have to do so that the text will also be centered vertically.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You following line can be the problem:

```
tv.layout(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);
```

The documentation for the [layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) function says the following:

```
public void layout (int l, int t, int r, int b)

Parameters: 
l : Left position, relative to parent
t : Top position, relative to parent 
r : Right position, relative to parent
b : Bottom position, relative to parent
```

So, you are asking your `TextView` to be at no distance from top and left of the parent.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it. Just tried with values greater than 0 but still the same. With that line I am just defining how big I want the TextView to be, which in this case, is as big as its parent.

Comment: okay. What does this gives you? `tv.layout(displayWidth/4, displayHeight/4, displayWidth/4, displayHeight/4);` ?

Comment: making all four values the same gives some NullPointerException. I changed them up a little to make the top and left values smaller than the bottom and right values. Still the same result. It only gets centered horizontically.